# What is the difference between quantum key distribution and quantum key exchange?

Tags: cryptography, key-distribution

Both the words 'Quantum Key Distribution' and 'Quantum Key Exchange' are used in quantum cryptography in the problem of a secure key distribution for encryption/decryption between parties. There are popular algorithms like the BB84, B94 and E91 protocols for the above-stated task.

However what I want to know is that is there a difference between the two terms 'Quantum Key Distribution (QKD)' and 'Quantum Key Exchange (QKE)' or both represent the same concept?

Comment: **Related**: [Key Exchange & key Distribution in symmetric key cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48071/key-exchange-key-distribution-in-symmetric-key-cryptography).

Answer (score 2):

Quantum key distribution (QKD) is a secure communication method that enables two parties to produce a shared random secret key known only to them, which can then be used to encrypt and decrypt messages. Quantum key distribution is only used to produce and distribute a key, not to transmit any message data. The algorithm most commonly associated with QKD is the one-time pad, as it is provably secure when used with a secret, random key. QKD is more of a communication architecture than a cryptographic protocol.

Quantum Key Exchange (QKE) on the other hand is a cryptographic concept originally explored by Donald Beaver. There is a [seminal paper of the deniability of QKE](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46035-7_23) published in 2002 itself. There are a few variants of QKE like authenticated QKE, Entanglement Distillation QKE etc. Please refer to this [recent paper on QKE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02245.pdf) with reference to the aspects of covert communication and entanglement distillation.

There are some clear distinctions between QKD and QKE such as the following.

- QKD usually relies on having an authenticated classical channel of communications whereas QKE is a collection of cryptographic properties of Quantum Information with a focus on the Quantum Computational Complexity theory
- QKD uses classical encryption schemes such as one-time-pads whereas QKE does not employ any classical cryptographic devices and schemes.